# How to trigger if statement jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quick question. I am trying to trigger an event when two 'container' divs no longer have any divs inside them.

My Script so far is as follows:

```
if (($('#Summary2 div').length) + ($('#Summary3 div').length)) == 0) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

My problem is -how do I get this piece of code to trigger? I think what happens is that it gets read once and then sits there idle as nothing triggers it.

Kind regards and thank you,
G

Comment: Either check every time you remove something from there (in which case having a function dedicated to this is helpful - never remove elements from there except through that function), or, less efficiently, set an interval to do the check every now and then. I strongly suggest the first approach, unless your code is such a mess that you remove the same elements from 471 different places.

Comment: Oh, another option - [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), a rather new spec, but works on all(ish) current browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code. On "**remove**" event may trigger.

```
$("#Summary2 div, #Summary3 div").on("remove", function () {
    if (($('#Summary2 div').length) + ($('#Summary3 div').length)) == 0) {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `remove` event. There is `DOMNodeRemoved`, which is deprecated.

Comment: That should have been noted in the answer; neither you nor OP mentioned jQuery-UI. Also, it only works for jQuery `.remove()`; if an element is removed by any other means (such as standard DOM `removeChild`), it will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check for div on specific time let us say every 1 hour then you can use setinterval as shown below :-

```
setInterval(
function(){
if ($('#Summary2 div').length + $('#Summary3 div').length == 0) {
    alert("hello");
}
}, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```